# Cannot Set Gamma and Hue for UVCCamera (Android USB Camera)

Tags: android, usb, android-camera, yuv

I am trying to change hue, contrast and gamma properties for online preview of usb camera connected to Android phone. I'm using the [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) library. Setting the mentioned properties with respective methods has no effect on the preview. Please see the code below:

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekbarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressChanged: " + progress);
        int step = 10;
        step = progress - mProgress;
        mProgress = progress;
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressChanged: camera gamma: " + mUVCCamera.getGamma());
        mUVCCamera.setGamma(mUVCCamera.getGamma() + step);
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressChanged: hue: " + mUVCCamera.getHue(100));
        mUVCCamera.setHue(mUVCCamera.getHue(100) + step);
    }
```

Logcat show that gamma and hue values are always 0. Why so, despite the fact that I am setting new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to change UVCCamera parameters, you need to set minimum and maximum values as well as default values for a certain parameter like saturation. It is done in the UVCCamera class as follows:

```
protected int mSaturationMin = 0, mSaturationMax = 100, mSaturationDef = 0;
```

After that, you can now call a method available in the API to set the parameter like `setSaturation(int)`, but make sure you call `updateCameraParams` afterwards. This will apply the effect immediately.